# Drill down heat map chart

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, heatmap, drilldown

I have a requirement of  `drill down` heat map chart.

I need some javascript framework. I have checked `extjs`, `highcharts`. But nothing appealing as such till now.

What I want is exactly like Google Analytics. First a world map

[image]

Once I click on USA, I am drilling down to state level

[image]

Do we have any google api? Any framework?

Answer (score -2):

I think Google was also using closure for google maps and analytics. https://developers.google.com/closure/

Comment: Pointing to a generic JavaScript library doesn't come close to addressing the question, IMO.